# Android custom list view?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my layout I need a custom list view like a box type.

How can do that ?

**My XML:**

```
   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="317dp"
     android:gravity="top"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

     <ListView android:id="@+id/slistview" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:divider="#2867EA"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        >
     </ListView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have a custom adapter inflate a custom layout for each row and set the adapter to listview. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: use custom adapter like this http://abhiandroidinfo.blogspot.in/2013/05/customised-listview-with-images.html

Comment: box type? could you insert any picture sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create custom list adapter and supply xml layout for each row.
here's a comprehensive tutorial that fits your needs:

[Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `customBaseadapter` and `viewHolder` ...

Comment: for multiline listview ..good tutorial here .. [link]http://vaibhavadhyapak.blogspot.in/2013/01/building-custom-multi-line-listview-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a xml for row of the list view and set the background of the row and create a custom adapter and set adapter to list view.

[custom list view](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text)